# Redirection Before Page Load

Tags: safari, safari-extension

I have an injection script--a start script--whose ultimate goal is to redirect to a different URL. That injection script needs to access the extension settings, so it sends a message to a global HTML file. That global file checks the settings and redirects to the appropriate URL by setting the `safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.url` property.

What I'm finding is that all too often, the interim page loads first making for an annoying UX at best and introducing errors at worst. I'm assuming that this is a result of the asynchronous nature of messaging, but I haven't been able to find a way to stop it.

Is there any way to prevent the default behavior (loading the originally requested page) while still reading from extension settings?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this simply isn't possible given the current state of the Safari extension API.

Comment: Did you try stopping the page load by calling `window.stop` in an injected (start) script? This seems to work for me.

Comment: I did not. I didn't see/know of that method. I'll check that out tonight. Thanks.